# Getting consistent colors for terminal and GUI emacs

Tags: colors

I've noticed that color definitions on the terminal and the GUI are not consistent.

For example on the GUI, there is a color `DarkOrchid2` defined, however this is not there for the terminal. Instead, the similar color is defined as `color-99` and the named colors are not supported.

Is there a way to get the colors consistent?

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. All applications running inside a terminal are at the mercy of what colors the terminal emulator chooses to use. All Emacs can do is ask that some characters be rendered in color 3, and others in color 12. The terminal emulator has a palette of colors that it uses, and this palette is often configurable. You should consult the documentation for your terminal emulator to see how to change that configuration.

Comment: Most of the popular terminal emulators now have the 256-color support pioneered by XTerm. There is also 24-bit color support (16 million colors) which is less popular. I don't know how to get Emacs to use these, but there's probably a way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Comment: Yes, if he has a `color-99` then he's probably already using 256 colors.

Comment: I'm sticking with terminal emacs right now. I'm hoping that there might be a way to import the terminal `color-<X>` settings into the gui.

Comment: What color settings do you want to import into what gui?